# Where can I find a standard set of rules for designing web pages?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css

I have been making webpages for about 5 years now. I'm a C# programmer but I do know HTML, JavaScript, and CSS by nature and all my websites seem to look like they just walked out of the year 1995's internet. Is there quick reference to a set of do's and don't in web design?

**Note:** Even though my websites don't look great, at least they work ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few links, older but still relevant:

[The Principles of Beautiful Web Design](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/principles-beautiful-web-design/)

[Five Simple Steps to designing with colour](http://www.markboulton.co.uk/journal/comments/five_simple_steps_to_designing_with_colour/)

[How C.R.A.P is Your Site Design?](http://thinkvitamin.com/features/design/how-crap-is-your-site-design/)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and assets for the sites you like? It's all there--that's what's great about the open web.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're looking more for visual help, but see this guide for some technical gotchas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

Comment: Yeah I was going for visual but this was helpful also.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good reference of don'ts:

http://csszengarden.com/?cssfile=http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/zen/sample.css

Comment: That's hilarious.

csszengarden.com is a great resource for learning from good designs (although you wouldn't know it if you never been to the site and only have seen the example linked here.)

Comment: Sadly, too many of my clients would love to see their site have more ... uh ... pizazz like that.

Comment: I can't believe I've never seen that one before. That's great!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the there really isn't a set of do's / don'ts. I'm not aware of any kind of CUA-like guidance for web applications for a given look/feel and user experience.

for aesthetics :

- [ASP.NET MVC Design Gallery](http://www.asp.net/mvc/gallery/default.aspx) - for MVC
- [ASP.NET Design Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336613.aspx) - for webforms
- [25 Magento site designs](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/05/25-magento-templates-for-your-e-commerce-business/)

I would also look at reading [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) on a regular basis (I am sure there are others) it has pointers on layouts, design templates, galleries, typography and things like optimizing different kinds of work flows in sites (e.g. shopping carts, non-profit sites etc).

It was amazing how on my last project just starting with one of the the asp.net templates made my app look better out of the box and that minimized the resistance of end users on their initial go around with the app. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just educate yourself on the principels of design ... things like the rule of thirds, balance, symmetry, contrast, rhythm & patterns, proportion (divine proportion).

Spend an hour searching "principles of design" and you may surprised what ideas come to you for your sites.

Answer (score 0):

This book was very useful to me when I started, and lots of people I've recommended it to have been happy with it:

[The Non-Designer's Web Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020168859X)

in fact her general book on design is almost as good, as it's mostly about the principles, not so much about the technical details.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [bulletproof css by dan cederholm](http://simplebits.com/publications/bulletproof/)